# How to access Android references within Android Studio

Tags: android, api, android-studio, intellij-idea, camera

My question relates to viewing documentation directly in Android Studio.

For those familiar with Eclipse, I can view all the methods and constructors of a class by clicking on that class and pressing shift and f2. This then takes me to a neat browser within Eclipse that lays out all method signatures and what they do, almost like google docs.

This saves me from having to go to google and search for that classes API each time. For example if I want to view the classes in the "Android.util.log" package, and in turn, the methods in each class, this can easily be done with Eclipse by adding external documentation. For Android Studio, the only way is to go to google and type "Android reference log package" or something, to be taken to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html.

Does something like this exist for Android Studio/InteillJ? If so, could someone please be kind enough to give me steps on how to set it up? I've tried the Ctrl+Q trick but this just gives me a very small overview of a class and not the actual methods within the class.

---

I also have 2 other questions - and I may get negged for this because I shouldn't ask more than one question in a post - but I feel that these questions are brief and shouldn't need it's own topic. If this poses too much of a problem, feel free to edit this post and I will accept the edit.

1. I want to create an Android app that makes use of the camera. I know
   theres 2 libraries that exist; android.hardware.camera and .camera2,
   the latter for API 21 and above. My project is intended to support
   API 15 to 24 (and anything newer that is released during
   development). Because .camera2 isn't supported by API 15-20, should I
   just use .camera throughout my project, or should I target specific API's with different code?
2. Thirdly, I'm not 100% sure about the concept of targetting various
   API levels. If I support API's 15 to 21 and import a library that
   say, only supports API 19 and up, and use it in my code, will
   Android Studio warn me that this code won't work on any devices
   running API 15-18, or will I only find out by testing my code? This saves me from constantly having to look at Android references to see which libraries are supported by which API's.

Comment: Ctrl+click/Cmd+click to get source files (+ javadoc kinda)

Comment: ctrl+space to show documentation

Comment: This only gives a brief overview and when I click on the hyperlinked classes I get an error saying the url can't be found.  I assume I need to somehow load the docs like you have to do with eclipse and JRE. The problem is I can't figure out how to do that. I digged up an old post that suggested looking at Platform Settings in Android Studio, but I can't find the option in Android studio anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the class documentation from Android Studio by **Holding down Ctrl key & click on the class name.**

For this to work you should have downloaded the **Sources for Android SDK** in Android SDK Manager. For API levels starting from 15, Sources for Android SDK is available in SDK manager & downloading that will give you the option to view a class documentation.

If you need documentation like in web doc, focus the mouse cursor on the class & **press Ctrl+Q** which will open a popup & then press **Shift+F1** or **select View External Documentation** icon from popup. You should download **Documentation for Android SDK** in SDK manager for this to work

Comment: Ignore my last comment if you read it.  When pressing ctrl and clicking, it takes me to the actual implementation.  What I want is basically just the method signatures and description, exactly how it's presented on developer www.developer.android.com/reference/packages.html.  This is possible with eclipse and java classes but I'm not sure if it's possible with android studio and Android packages.

Comment: For some reason shift+f1 does nothing, and neither can I see the "View external documentation" link.

Comment: @user3186023 So does Ctrl+Q opens popup??

Comment: Yeah, ctrl + q works as you said, but nothing beyond that.

Comment: I think you haven't downloaded Documentaion for Android SDK using SDK manager. If it is not downloaded, the option won't be visible & shift+f1 don't work.

Comment: It says "Installed"  under SDK tools so it's definitely downloaded.